# Is it possible to execute assembly language instructions in the immediate window

Tags: debugging, assembly, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

I have written a small program in C++. I have the Disassembly window side-by-side the C++ program window.
I want to see what happens at the assembly level, when I execute assembly instructions in the immediate window. But, I am not able to do so.
For example, when I type "add eax, 1" in the immediate window, I get the result "identifier "add" is undefined".

Is there a way to execute assembly instructions such that I am able to do something like "add eax, 1", while debugging? I want to do this so that I can understand what is going on at the assembly level better.
Any help is highly appreciated.

I researched the internet a lot, but couldn't find a solution to my question.

C++ code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int AddMe(int a, int b)
{
    int c;
    c = a + b;
    return c;
}

int main() 
{
    AddMe(10, 20);
    return 0;
}
```

snippet of equivalent assembly code:

```
int main() 
{
00BCDC40  push        ebp  
00BCDC41  mov         ebp,esp  
00BCDC43  sub         esp,0C0h  
00BCDC49  push        ebx  
00BCDC4A  push        esi  
00BCDC4B  push        edi  
00BCDC4C  lea         edi,[ebp-0C0h]  
00BCDC52  mov         ecx,30h
```

Assembly Watch window:

```
+       (int*)(ebp) 0x001ef898 {2029812}    int *
+       (int*)(esp) 0x001ef878 {2029720}    int *
+       (int*)(esi) 0x00bc1712 {TryCatch2.exe!_mainCRTStartup} {9030121}    int *
+       (int*)(edi) 0x00bc1712 {TryCatch2.exe!_mainCRTStartup} {9030121}    int *
+       (int*)ecx   0x00000001 {???}    int *
+       (int*)(ecx) 0x00000001 {???}    int *
+       (int*)(eax) 0x00615180 {6377864}    int *
+       (int*)(edx) 0x00614fe8 {6377728}    int *
+       (int*)(esi) 0x00bc1712 {TryCatch2.exe!_mainCRTStartup} {9030121}    int *
+       (int*)(ebx) 0x002e7000 {67174400}   int *
```

Actual result:
When I type "add eax, 1" in immediate window, it gives the result "identifier "add" is undefined".
Expected result:
When I type "add eax, 1" in immediate window, it should add 1 to eax register.

Comment: Instructions execute from a location in memory. Many instructions will have results that depend on the location form which they're executed. Also, the instruction pointer generally changes when executing an instruction, but where would it go to if you force an instruction to happen?

Comment: @ThomasJager, so there is no way I can change even the contents of registers (registers containing variables), during debugging?

Comment: Changing those is generally easy and well-documented for whatever tools you're using. You just wouldn't do it using your own processor instructions.

Comment: If you look at the "registers" debug window, you can make changes to their values.

Comment: Assuming it's similar to Visual Studio, try debug -> window -> dissassembly to open a debug assembly window.

Comment: in some assemblers you can modify the memory, like in old DOS environment in turbo debugger, you can actually write `add ax,1` and it will get assembled and written into memory where you were pointing, and then you can step onto it with debugger, to execute it. But it's not like evaluating the instruction in evaluate/immediate window, you are actually executing it in some memory/context. With modern OS this gets less straightforward because the executable area of memory is often read-only (unless the debugger will reconfigure it for modification and then back), depends on your tools.

Comment: Then again it should be quite easy to just write some test assembly in assembler source, compile and debug over that in the debugger. As long as it's small assembly file, it should assemble and execute in tenths of second, with well set breakpoing and environment it should be quite close to what you imagine with "immediate" window, just different approach. (but honestly, you should be able to understand the instruction from it's formal description in the reference guide ... I'm not saying it's easy and I fully understand you want to see it in action in debugger, I'm saying you *should*)

Answer (score 1):

We can't make changes to register values in the Immediate Window. But, we can make changes to register values in the Registers window, and the watch window (by simply editing the register values).

Comment: Hi Vikram, thanks for your sharing and please mark it as [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, It just a reminder :)